# Adding textoverlay to rtps steam and saving it to a file

Tags: python, c, gstreamer

Okey I have this commands:

**This one displays stream with textoverlay over it**

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://ip/url ! decodebin ! textoverlay text = "Hello world" !  autovideosink
```

**This one saves stream to a mp4 using mp4 container**

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://ip/url ! rtsh264depay ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=someFile.mp4
```

How could I do this together in same time ? I mean I want to save file with text overlay over it ? If I understand well I should decode it with decodebin then decode it again but Iam lil bit lost there .

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly simple and you basically have it.

If you combine your two pipelines it should work just fine(depending on caps and the like).

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://ip/url ! decodebin ! textoverlay text = "Hello world" ! x264enc ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=someFile.mp4
```

Same idea but with Mpeg4

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://ip/url ! decodebin ! textoverlay text = "Hello world" ! avenc_mpeg4 ! mp4mux ! filesink location=someFile.mp4
```

Comment: Well I came up with same idea after reading documentation. Rtspsrc has  1 pad and it's source(output x/rtps).Decodebin has 1 sink and 1 source pad and it can accept x/rtps on sink .Decodebin source output is a raw video .Textoverlay has 1 sink and 1 source pad both accept/generate raw video.X264enc raw video to raw h264 video. h264parse is parsing that.mp4mux is adding it to a mux and at last we have filesink it legit if you think logically but after writing that in terminal I got error.

Comment: this file contains no playable streams

Comment: when saving stream to a file you must use -e flag so that mp4mux can finalize process.